# What is the detailed solution to this problem?

Tags: calculus, physics

I've been trying to solve this problem from my Calculus textbook. ( the one attached as a pic ) the solutions page says that the answer is 550 Ib-ft

I couldn't solve it unfortunately. Please provide a step by step solution to this problem explaining which quantities were used in which integrations and why.

Thanks in advance

[image]

If you're wondering, the textbook is Calculus with Analytic Geometry by George Simmions 2ed Section 7.7 problem 5 page 249

Comment: Unless there is an assumption on the rate at which the bucket is being lifted, this cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2):

$$W=Fd$$
Total work = Work to lift bucket + Work to lift sand $\rightarrow W= Wb +Ws =Fb(d) + Fs(d)$

1.$Wb$
$$Fb=5lb$$
$$dWb=5dx$$
$$Wb= \int_0^{10} 5dx = 50 Lbft$$

2.$Ws$

Note that the sand weighs $60 lb$ at the beginning and $40 lb$ after being lifted $10m$, with the loss being uniform. Thus the force is unfiromly variable with respect to the position of the bucket, which means we need to formulate a linear equation for the force:

$$Fs=60-2x$$
You could check this equation by plugging in values for $x=0,5,10$
$$dWs=(60-2x)dx$$
$$Ws= \int_0^{10} (60-2x)dx = 500Lbft $$

$$W=500Lbft + 50Lbft = 550Lbft$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the effort spent in explaining the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$work = \int f\ dx$

$f(0) = 65\\
f(10) = 45\\
f(x) = 65-2x$

$\int_0^{10} 65-2x \ dx$

Comment: Why is f(x) = 65 - 2x ?

Comment: If the sand is leaking out at a uniform rate, and 20 pounds leaks out over 10 ft.  then 2 pounds leaks out every foot.